# Laragon can not include php pear folder

Tags: laragon

If I go to my localhost link it displays this error:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/Users/GuylianWasHier/OneDrive - ROC Ter AA/1. School/1. Web Development/2. WebDev Projects/index.php' (include_path='.;C:/laragon/etc/php/pear') in Unknown on line 0

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The Laragon's default document root is: C:\laragon\www
Please move "2. WebDev Projects/index.php" to that location.

Note: Don't use space in your folder name.

Comment: Actually, Laragon's default document root is customizable, so it can be wherever you want.

Comment: Also, in Windows, you may use spaces but be aware that you might need to wrap the value in double quotes when you specify it in a text file or at the command line. It is not recommended, though, to avoid problems.